# I am getting error on wsdl

Tags: php, wsdl, moodle

I am trying to access a web service on moodle.But i get the error Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\wamp\www\curlsimp.php on line 118.Can anybody tell me what the problem is?

```
    $functionname = 'core_user_create_users';
    $user1 = new stdClass();
     $user1->username = 'abcd';
    $user1->password =  'Password123!';
    $user1->firstname = 'ali';
    $user1->lastname = 'asdsad';
   $user1->email = 'asd@asd.com';
    $user1->city = 'apo';
    $user1->country = 'addfa';
     $user1->auth = 'manual';
    $params = array($user1);


   echo $WSDL;

   // SOAP CALL
    $serverurl = 'http://localhost/moodle/webservice/soap/server.php?<WSDL>&wstoken=57e86ddeb6e132338a629ffef3552a9d';
 ///Do the main soap call
   $client = new SoapClient($serverurl);
   try {
  $resp = $client->__soapCall($functionname, array($params));
   }
 catch (SoapFault $e) {
 exit($e->faultstring);
     }
```

Comment: do you really want the literal string `<WSDL>` in your $serverurl? 'cause it seems kinda out of place there. also: what line is line 118 in your code?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann is correct

Comment: line 118 is $client = new SoapClient($serverurl);